# Python Bottle multiple file upload

Tags: python, bottle

I wish to upload multiple files to a Bottle server.

Single file upload works well and by modifying the HTML input tag to be "multiple", the browse button allows the selection of multiple files. The upload request handler only loads the last file. How can I get all the files uploaded in one go?

The code I am experimenting with:

```
    from bottle import route, request, run

    import os

    @route('/fileselect')
    def fileselect():
        return '''
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Category:      <input type="text" name="category" />
      Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload" multiple />
      <input type="submit" value="Start upload" />
    </form>
        '''

    @route('/upload', method='POST')
    def do_upload():
        category   = request.forms.get('category')
        upload     = request.files.get('upload')
        print dir(upload)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)
        if ext not in ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg'):
            return 'File extension not allowed.'

        #save_path = get_save_path_for_category(category)
        save_path = "/home/user/bottlefiles"
        upload.save(save_path) # appends upload.filename automatically
        return 'OK'

    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" meanst that the body of received upload is multipart. That means that you received all files in one separated by some boundary and hopefully described with MIME headers. Take a look at saved file and see whether there are more than one in it. If there are, then you'll have to parse multipart. Else see how bottle handles multiparts, and which method in upload object can help you to get individual file. Maybe you can call get("upload") more than once.

Comment: use `request.files.getall` instead of `request.files.get`?

Answer (score 5):

[mata's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642717/python-bottle-multiple-file-upload/31644337#comment51232480_31642717) works. You can get the list of uploaded files by calling [`getall()`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.MultiDict.getall) on `request.files`.

```py
@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    uploads = request.files.getall('upload')
    for upload in uploads:
        print upload.filename
    return "Found {0} files, did nothing.".format(len(uploads))
```

Comment: Yes that works thank you. This is so much easier than mucking with html/javascript.